# mating proposal for genetic algorithms

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

I am using a genetic algorithm to solve an optimization problem. However, I want a mating process that enables to create new solutions that are outside the range of current solutions. In the book: Practical Genetic Algorithms I have seen:

$$p_\mbox{new} = B*(p_1-p_2) + p_1$$

where $p_\mbox{new}$ is the new solution, and $p_1$ and $p_2$ are two different current solutions. $B$ is a random number between $[0,1]$.

But the problem is that this enables negative value, and my cromosomes can't be negative. I thought about the following:

$$p_\mbox{new} = A*p_1+B*p_2$$

where A and B are random numbers between [0,1]

Has this method been used before? Any opinion if it can work?

The other idea I had was just to used the one of Practical Genetic and take the absolute value, i.e.:
$$
p_\mbox{new} = \left| B*(p_1-p_2) + p_1 \right|
$$

Comment: I adjusted your text so as to use mathJax (which is very easy; have a look at the changes).  In future questions, please do this to make it more readable.

Comment: @IvanMartinez: it would be helpful to get more details about the range of $p$ values. I get that they have to be positive, any other constraints?

Comment: no other! Only that they can't be negative!

Comment: I do not see the problem; $p_{new}$ is nonnegative when $p_1$ and $p_2$ are nonnegative.

Comment: But how can I know if this mating process converges to an optimal solution?